# How to call pg_dump from app engine

Tags: google-cloud-platform, postgresql, google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql

How do I call pg_dump from my .NET app engine instance? I use Google Cloud SQL. I need pg_dump to specify specific flags when exporting my database.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to set database flags to a Postgres Cloud SQL instance you may follow [this guide](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/flags#setting_a_database_flag) from the documentation.

According to [the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/import-export/exporting#external-server), when using `pg_dump` on a Cloud SQL instance you have to use `--no-owner`, `--format=plain` and `--no-acl`.

Comment: Thanks, but i was looking for pg_dump flags. I need to export a single schema, data-only.

Comment: I have updated my answer. If that information doesn't suit your needs I will need a better explanation on your use-case in order for me to better understand your issue and help you further.